# Scheduled jenkins build to run only when change is detected

Tags: git, jenkins

I am familiar with running jenkins build by doing a poll on git repository.

But my question is, I have automated builds that are scheduled to run at some specific time. If there are no changes I would like to not trigger the scheduled build.

Any suggestions please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Change your automated builds to *poll* at a specific time for changes.

Answer (score 1):

use POLL SCM which provides cron scheduler ex : * 2 * * * which executes ever day at 2am.
It also checks for any changes made in git/source prior to this time, if there is changes made then build will start else no.
ref : https://dzone.com/articles/polling-subversion-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Best way in my mind is to use hooks. Look at `post-receive` hook

https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger build by following two methods:

1. **Poll SCM** :  periodically polls the SCM to check whether changes were made (i.e. new commits) and builds the project if new commits where pushed since the last build
2. **build periodically** : builds the project periodically even if nothing has changed.